# using Spring boot empty log file is getting generated

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging

I have a simple Spring boot rest API application. I am managing logs via the below properties mentioned in the application.property file.

logging.level.org.springframework=INFO

logging.level.com.learning=DEBUG

logging.file.name=application.log

logging.pattern.file= %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%

I can see logs are getting printed on console but same logs I don't see in the log file which got created via application.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: I assume `application.property` was a typo ? The correct is `application.properties`

Answer (score 0):

Change the logging.pattern.file to `logging.pattern.file= %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] - %msg%`